# Using PowerShell to Assign Teams Policies to Users

Tags: powershell, office365, microsoft-teams

I would like to assign Microsoft Office 365 Teams policies to users via PowerShell. However I cannot find the right cmdlet to use to do this. I have looked at 
[Get-CsUserPolicyAssignment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/get-csuserpolicyassignment?view=teams-ps) but it seems that this is still in beta so I can't run it ("not recognized as a cmdlet"). Ideally I want to be able to assign a group of users to a policy in Teams via powerShell, I just can't find any code examples from which to start. Anyone have anything that can help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Grant-CsTeamsChannelsPolicy to set Team policies to individual users.

I found this script in the net which uses the required module(Which you mentioned).

https://blog.admindroid.com/managing-private-channels-in-microsoft-teams/

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by connecting to the Azure Active Directory PowerShell for Graph module and the Skype for Business PowerShell module.

For example:

Get the GroupObjectId of the particular group.

```
$group = Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString "Contoso Marketing"
```

Get the members of the specified group.

```
$members = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -All $true | Where-Object {$_.ObjectType -eq "User"}
```

Assign all users in the group to a particular teams policy. In this example, it's Marketing Teams Policy.

```
$members | ForEach-Object { Grant-CsTeamsChannelsPolicy -PolicyName "Marketing Teams Policy" -Identity $_.UserPrincipalName}
```

More information:

[Manage teams policies in Microsoft Teams](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-policies)

[Using Powershell to apply Messaging Policies to Teams Users](https://practical365.com/collaboration/teams/using-powershell-to-apply-messaging-policies-to-teams-users/)